# How can I save a column value to a variable in SQL C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am using windows forms C# and SQL. I have a table consists of two column:

Column1 = myID (primary key and unique ID)

Column2 = DateTime.

The following code inserts date/Time into the table:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
         cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into TableDate_Time (DateTime ) values (@DateTime)");


        cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;  
         cm.Connection = cn;
         cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

     // something like:  var varID = the current myID value

   }
```

My Question is: How can I save the last row value of myID column into a variable whenever I click the button? any idea? Thank you

Comment: is myID a `IDENTITY` column or is it a `uniqueidentifer` column?

Comment: @  Scott Chamberlain. it is uniqueidentifer .

Comment: You should be explicit about that in your question, the answers with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will not work with that.

Comment: @naouf how is defined the default value for that column? Using the NEWID T-SQL function?

Comment: @naouf do you need to specify the new ID or does it have a default like `NEWID()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql Server (and other database systems) you could pass two commands in the same text. Now T-SQL allows you to get back the last IDENTITY value generated for your connection using the command "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()".

Thus your code will be

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string cmdText = @"Insert into TableDate_Time 
                       (DateTime ) values (@DateTime);
                       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
     using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("...."))
     using(SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
         cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
         cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;  
         int id = Convert.ToInt32(cm.ExecuteScalar());
         .... 
     }
}
```

Instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, call `ExecuteScalar` that returns the first column of the first row in the last command executed here (The SELECT).  Note that it is a good practice to enclose every disposable object like the connection and the command in a using statement to have a correct exit path for your code in case of exceptions (one that doesn't forget to dispose these objects)

**EDIT**

If your ID column is not an `IDENTITY` column but an `uniqueidentifier` there are more problems. I suppose that your table has defined a default for the column ID using the NEWID() function of T-SQL

In this case you need to change your query to

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string cmdText = @"Insert into TableDate_Time 
                       (DateTime ) OUTPUT INSERTED.myID values (@DateTime)";
     using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("...."))
     using(SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
         cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
         cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;  
         Guid id = (Guid)cm.ExecuteScalar();
         .... 
     }
}
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of, I have had problems where triggers can royally screw up queries with output statements that print directly out. If there is any chance of a trigger being on it it may be better to output to a variable then print the variable in a separate select.

Comment: Yes, just testing on ad hoc table to see if the ExecuteScalar returns also the Guid. Well too late, already answered by Mr. Stanley above

Comment: @ Steve . your first code worked very well thank you. one last question please: what if the myID column gets its value from a textbox but not automatically add by default ? can we use ExecuteScalar (); if not what to use. thank you

Comment: Well, if you have a value for the myID column inserted by your users then you can't have an IDENTITY column or a uniqueidentifier column with the NEWID function as default. You should change that column to an integer (or a nvarchar) and pass the value typed in the textbox as another parameter and change accordingly your INSERT query THEN use ExecuteNonQuery . But this probably defeats the purpose of the myID columns  as a PRIMARY KEY. Sorry but your new question now raises many doubts on what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the new ID is generated in the database via a column default, you could use the `OUTPUT` clause to return the ID of the new record:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableDate_Time (DateTime) OUTPUT inserted.myID VALUES (@DateTime)");

    cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;  
    cm.Connection = cn;
    Guid newID = (Guid)cm.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Some other things to consider that are not germane you your problem:

- Don't put direct SQL logic in a button click event handler - use a separate class for data management
- Wrap you commands and connections in `using` blocks so that they are closed in a timely fashion, even if there is an exception.

Comment: One thing to be careful of, I have had problems where triggers can royally screw up queries with output statements that print directly out. If there is any chance of a trigger being on it it may be better to output to a variable then print the variable in a separate select.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.  Just add the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
         cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into TableDate_Time (DateTime ) values (@DateTime)");


        cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;  
         cm.Connection = cn;
         int returnValue = 0;
         SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
         param.ParameterName = "ReturnParameter";
         param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
         cm.Parameters.Add(param);

         cm.Connection.Open();
         cm.ExecuteNonQuery();    
   }
```

And in your stored procedure (or sql query) add:

```
DECLARE @ID int = (Select SCOPE_IDENTITY())

RETURN @ID
```

Comment: I don't know if `ReturnValue` works with text queries, you would need to have `cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` in there for it to work (I think).

Comment: The ReturnValue parameter is assigned from the RETURN statement in T-SQL not from a SELECT This code doesn't return the last identity value, by the way, where is the stored procedure here?

Comment: You're right about the stored procedure.  Whoops!  Maybe I should delete, but I'll hold off for now and see if the OP can clarify.